# Can iMovie Projects be stored in iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, imovie

I have enabled iCloud for iMovie, but they don't show up in the iMovie Media of my other MacBook.

Is it possible to access iMovie Projects with iCloud?

iMovie is enabled:
[image]

Can't see iMovie in iCloud folder:
[image]

Neither in the web:
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify "iMovie files" ? Ones you edit, or the final mov output ?

Comment: Hi @ankii, the ones I'm editing (the so called Projects).

Comment: I'm a bit irritated about the "iCloud backup" statement. iCloud is not a backup, it's just cloud-based storage. Did you actually store a project in iCloud already (from within iMovie)?

Comment: @nohillside, this is exactly what I mean. I have never stored an iMovie Project in iCloud (this is what I need)

Comment: You should be able to do this from within iMovie

Comment: Please open iMovie and check if you can store to iCloud from there. Adding yet another Findet screenshot doesn‘t add new information.

Answer (score 2):

> Choose File > Open Library > New.
>
> In the Save dialog that appears, type a name for the new library, and
>   navigate to the location where you want to save it.
>
> The default location is the Movies folder in your home folder.
>
> Click Save.
>
> A new library is created in the location you chose, and a new, empty
>   event with today’s date is created.

https://help.apple.com/imovie/mac/10.1/#/mov3fa25bae7

I don't have iMovie, so you need to check if iCloud is allowed there. If not, you need to copy paste items from `~/Movies` to iCloud.

As for iCloud backup that you mention, it could be system preferences etc that are backed up, not the Library itself.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue has not been solved by Apple yet. I ended up by saving iMovie projects to an external usb drive and working there with the other Mac I have.